# Log all output from a shell command

Tags: ruby

I'm writing a ruby script that calls `apt-get`. I would like to log/display all the output from the `apt-get` command.

Backticks, `%x` and the rest mostly return the final output (if at all).
I've also looked at IO.popen and Open3.popen series, but they stop logging after the first message.

Is there a way to dump all output as it happens from the shell command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [IO::popen](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/IO.html#method-c-popen) for this:

```
IO.popen("apt-get install foobar") do |apt|
  apt.each do |line|
    puts line
  end
end
```

Hope this helps

Comment: `popen3` also allows capturing the STDERR channel.